# How to perform a task if user doesn't abort it explicitly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'd like to have a dialog box which says something along the lines of "Computer will shut down in 30 seconds, press `Cancel` to abort" and shut it down in case there has been no input.

I've checked out Tk and pymsgbox but this is the case with both of them:
The user has to click on `OK` or `Cancel`  before the next instruction is executed.

This is what I've done so far:
1. Create a separate thread where the message box is opened.
2. Set a global variable in case the user responds to the message box.
3. In the main thread check if the user has responded continuously for N seconds (using sleep in between every check).
4. If the user hasn't cancelled the operation in N seconds then shutdown the system from the main thread.

This works but feels somewhat hacky. Is there a better way to do it? Preferably in Tkinter, but I'm open to using any other package too.

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 14 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.0.5 of PyMsgBox now has a `timeout` argument where you can pass the number of milliseconds before the dialog box closes. In this case, the function will return `'Timeout'`.

```
>>> alert('Hello!', timeout=5000) # closes after 5 seconds
```